# React/JSX - how to code an editable input with initial content provided via props that only updates its parent when submitted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All the examples I have found that keep local state can't provide an initial value for the input. In my case a parent component retrieves field from a server and passes these to my input form where the fields shall be editable. But I don't want to pass each change back up the hierarchy if I can avoid it, rather only when the form is submitted (either via button or by pressing enter)

Update: the usage is as follows. Imagine a todo list. The top level holds the list and the detail component. When I click at the list the detail should update to show the selected todo text. That text should be editable.

So as far the the detail component goes the initial state of the input is the text from the list that gets passed down in props. It needs to change when a different todo in the list is selected. On the other hand I should be able to edit it and when submit triggered that todo text should be passed back up via a callback prop.

So I have to keep local state to collect the input, but I want that state to be initialized with the existing todo text from the list. If I use the Facebook example of an uncontrolled form, I find the edited text remains displayed when I switch to a different todo in the list. Maybe I'm doing it wrong or is it a conceptual problem? Using controlled input initializing the state in the constructor doesn't work either because the constructor only gets called once (not on each re-render)!

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the lifecycle method componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops) where I can set the state to the new props. This method gets called each time a re-render becomes necessary - in my case because the parent changes the childs props.
See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial state based on the property passed in from the parent, then edit that state in the component before submitting with the form submission

Comment: The question is how? Where do I set the initial state? The constructor only gets called once, so setting it there means it will have the same initial value for the life-time of the component. I will add an explanation of how I am using the component: basically it is the detail in a master/detail UI.